# Change default options in pandas

Tags: python, configuration, pandas, ipython

I'm wondering if there's any way to change the default display options for pandas. I'd like to change the display formatting as well as the display width each time I run python, eg:

```
pandas.options.display.width = 150
```

I see the defaults are hard-coded in `pandas.core.config_init`. Is there some way in pandas to do this properly? Or if not, is there some way to set up ipython at least to change the config each time I import pandas? Only thing I can think of is making my own mypandas library that wraps pandas with some extra commands issued each time it's loaded. Any better ideas?

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#setting-startup-options-in-python-ipython-environment):

> Using startup scripts for the python/ipython environment to import
>   pandas and set options makes working with pandas more efficient. To do
>   this, create a .py or .ipy script in the startup directory of the
>   desired profile. An example where the startup folder is in a default
>   ipython profile can be found at:
>
> ```
> $IPYTHONDIR/profile_default/startup
> ```
>
> More information can be found in the ipython documentation. An example
>   startup script for pandas is displayed below:
>
> ```
> import pandas as pd
> pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 999)
> pd.set_option('precision', 5)
> ```

(or use the new form `pd.options.display.max_rows = 999`).

You also asked:

> -- is there any way to only run the pandas code when I import pandas from within ipython? it takes quite a while to import pandas, so I'd rather not do it every time I launch a new ipython instance

As a workaround, you could import pandas in the background. See [Import python modules in the background in REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47816669/import-python-modules-in-the-background-in-repl).

Comment: In case you are looking for the location of IPYTHONDIR, default directory is: ~/.ipython/

Comment: Would upvote this 10x if I could. Wish I found this *years* ago. Cheers mate!  (And a thank you to @Guido as well.)

Answer (score 3):

As described here, there are [iPython config files](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.2/html/config/customization.html#ipy-user-conf-py):

```
# Most of your config files and extensions will probably start
# with this import

import IPython.ipapi
ip = IPython.ipapi.get()

# You probably want to uncomment this if you did %upgrade -nolegacy
# import ipy_defaults

import os
import pandas


def main():

    #ip.dbg.debugmode = True
    ip.dbg.debug_stack()

    # uncomment if you want to get ipython -p sh behaviour
    # without having to use command line switches
    import ipy_profile_sh
    import jobctrl

    # Configure your favourite editor?
    # Good idea e.g. for %edit os.path.isfile

    #import ipy_editors

    # Choose one of these:

    #ipy_editors.scite()
    #ipy_editors.scite('c:/opt/scite/scite.exe')
    #ipy_editors.komodo()
    #ipy_editors.idle()
    # ... or many others, try 'ipy_editors??' after import to see them

    # Or roll your own:
    #ipy_editors.install_editor("c:/opt/jed +$line $file")


    o = ip.options
    # An example on how to set options
    #o.autocall = 1
    o.system_verbose = 0

    #import_all("os sys")
    #execf('~/_ipython/ns.py')


    # -- prompt
    # A different, more compact set of prompts from the default ones, that
    # always show your current location in the filesystem:

    #o.prompt_in1 = r'\C_LightBlue[\C_LightCyan\Y2\C_LightBlue]\C_Normal\n\C_Green|\#>'
    #o.prompt_in2 = r'.\D: '
    #o.prompt_out = r'[\#] '

    # Try one of these color settings if you can't read the text easily
    # autoexec is a list of IPython commands to execute on startup
    #o.autoexec.append('%colors LightBG')
    #o.autoexec.append('%colors NoColor')
    o.autoexec.append('%colors Linux')

    pandas.options.display.width = 150


# some config helper functions you can use
def import_all(modules):
    """ Usage: import_all("os sys") """
    for m in modules.split():
        ip.ex("from %s import *" % m)

def execf(fname):
    """ Execute a file in user namespace """
    ip.ex('execfile("%s")' % os.path.expanduser(fname))

main()
```

Probably better to make [separate Python profiles](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.10.2/html/config/customization.html#ipython-profiles). (The code is untested).

Comment: okay, that's a start -- is there any way to only run the pandas code when I import pandas from within ipython? it takes quite a while to import pandas, so I'd rather not do it every time I launch a new ipython instance.

Comment: @Noah: Well, if you make different profiles, you can make a "cust_pandas" profile, and that will load pandas with your customization when iPython, omitting it will just load standard iPython. That's the best I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by actually going into the pandas folder (found using `pandas.__file__`). Inside the pandas folder there is a core folder with the `config_init.py` file. The lines

```
cf.register_option('large_repr', 'truncate', pc_large_repr_doc,
                       validator=is_one_of_factory(['truncate', 'info']))
```

set the default options. So you can change the second argument to 'info'

```
cf.register_option('large_repr', 'info', pc_large_repr_doc,
                       validator=is_one_of_factory(['truncate', 'info']))
```

and then by default pandas will print summary table if the data frame exceeds `max_rows` or `max_columns`, which you can also change the default for in this file. I'm not sure if this is safe behavior, but it worked for me.

Comment: yeah, I'm trying to avoid editing the pandas library as I'm running pandas on a slew of different computers and would like to be able to update it as frequently as the updates come out

Comment: Gotcha. That's beyond me then.