# Import python modules in the background in REPL

Tags: python, python-import, background-process, read-eval-print-loop

Some python modules, notably `matplotlib`, take a long time to load

```
start = datetime.datetime.now(); import numpy, pandas, matplotlib, sklearn; datetime.datetime.now() - start
```

takes half a second with cached files, and several seconds for [non-cached files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system). Is there a way to load these modules in the background, when in the Python interpreter?

Comment: It took `0:00:00.645208` on my 5½ year old Macbook Pro. This is disrupting your workflow?

Comment: @RyanSandridge: if it happens for the 100th time, it does (similar value for me). More importantly: if the files are not cached, it can take several seconds. So it's either type it and have the next `>>>` prompt available, or feel slightly bored, wait, maybe switch tasks, ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can import modules in separate threads. Here is the solution.

Create a file `load_modules.py`:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import importlib
import sys

modules_to_load = ['numpy', 'pandas', 'matplotlib']


def do_import(module_name):
    thismodule = sys.modules[__name__]

    module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
    setattr(thismodule, module_name, module)
    print(module_name, 'imported')


executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
for module_name in modules_to_load:
    executor.submit(do_import, module_name)
```

Then you can start interpreter with a command:

```
python -ic "exec(open(\"load_modules.py\").read(), globals())"
```

Or just run

```
exec(open("load_modules.py").read(), globals())
```

in your interpreter to load modules.

Comment: Thank you. How could this be implemented as a function `bg_load(module_name)`?