# How do I expand the output display to see more columns - for all future runs?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

When printing a Dataframe in the console I wish to display more columns than the default.
There are plenty of references to use:

> import pandas as pd
>
> pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 800)

but there is a need to run this command at every debug.

I am looking for a configuration that will set the default max_row value to a larger value for all future runs.

Working with python 2.7.13, pandas 0.24.1

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default options in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944930/change-default-options-in-pandas)

Comment: Thanks @Chris but the answers there solve it through iPython which does not work for any python IDE.